# Where would I ask a question about finding companies that rent out blocks of IP addresses?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking for companies that rent out blocks of /21 (IP addresses). In which Stack would I ask that?

I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow, and I have been scolded before for misposting.

Answer (score 10):

This isn't a suitable question for any Stack Exchange site as it stands.

It falls under the [shopping question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) (off site resource request).

If you can phrase it in such a way as to actually ask about the issue you are trying to solve (the problem causing you to need to rent out blocks of /21 ip addresses), it may find a good place on the network.

Comment: cna you link that so?

Comment: @user2864066 - To what so? I am saying it is not a suitable question as it stands, so there isn't one.